# Understanding a series representation of the logarithm of the zeta function

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I am reading through M. Ram Murty's *Problems in Analytic Number Theory* and have the following question regarding the first step in his proof of Dirichlet's Theorem.

Given this definition for the [zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function):

$$\zeta(s) = \prod\limits_{p}\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p^s}\right)^{-1}$$

Murty presents the following argument as the first step:

$$\log\zeta(s) = -\sum\limits_{p}\log\left(1 - \dfrac{1}{p^s}\right) = \sum\limits_{p}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{np^{ns}}\right)$$

I am not clear how he is able to remove the negative sign and the $\log$ to get to the last result.

I assume that he is using the [Euler Product Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_the_Euler_product_formula_for_the_Riemann_zeta_function):

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^s} = \prod\limits_{p} \dfrac{1}{1 - p^{-s}}$$

But I don't see how this allows him to get to the last expression.

Thanks very much,

-Larry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just using the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$ in the vicinity of $0$

Comment: Thanks very much.  I knew that it was something simple.

Comment: Specifically, $$-\log(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$$

Comment: Great.  Now, super clear.